# Execute procedure in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have create a stored procedure but when I am executing this procedure but its showing some error. I don't know how to pass the variable value in which order?

```
create procedure usp_cust4
@EMPLOYEE_ID float(10),
@EMP_NAME nvarchar(255),
@DEPARTMENT_ID nvarchar(255),
@DEPARTMENT_NAME nvarchar(255),
@EMP_SALARY float(10)
as 
update cust 
set
Emp_Name=@EMP_NAME,
Dept_ID=@DEPARTMENT_ID,
Dept_Name=@DEPARTMENT_NAME,
Salary=@EMP_SALARY
where Emp_id=@EMPLOYEE_ID*
```

Answer (score 3):

```
exec usp_cust4 1, 'Smith', 1, 'Marketing', 1000
```

Comment: ya,Its work for me..! This means that we have to pass the variables value in the same sequence as they are present in the declare section.Or i have to pass values as they are used in Update statement.

Comment: @manojkumarsingh: either you pass them in the **same order** as defined - or you need to **specify the parameter name** `exec usp_cust4 @EMP_SALARY = 10987, @EMP_NAME = "Manoj"  .....`

Answer (score 2):

```
exec usp_cust4
@EMPLOYEE_ID      = 1,
@EMP_NAME         = 'something',
@DEPARTMENT_ID    = 's23',
@DEPARTMENT_NAME  = 'abc',
@EMP_SALARY       = 10987
```

Comment: That one is more easy to understand for Begineers